# Docker container can't reach host services

Tags: docker

I am running a nodejs app in a docker (v 20.10.2) container on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (this is for dev purpose only)

My docker-compose config

```
  test:
    container_name: forge_test
    restart: always
    image: "node:lts"
    volumes:
      - ../src:/home/node/app
    command: "node test.js"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

In the docker, I can ping `host.docker.internal` (which does not work without extra_hosts), however I can not reach any services that I have running on any port (the port I am actually trying to reach is 7545 but none work) on the host.

Searching for a few hours now, no solutions I have found (adding docker0 to iptable, adding docker.host.internal to /etc/hosts) work.

Am I missing something? Could there be a firewall blocking access somewhere (II have ufw installed but tbh I don't really know how to use it)?

I can't find any similar issue where `host.docker.internal` can be pinged but the posrts not accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that the problem comes from ufw not allowing connections from docker containers on host ports.
Deactivating it helped for now, since it's only for dev purpose.